# Is the xxm step by step install tutorial clear enough?

Tags: delphi, documentation, delphi-7

I know the [xxm install guide](http://xxm.sourceforge.net/install.html) is a lot to read and doesn't get you up and running as fast and easily as it would when you've seen it done.

So I've [installed xxm](http://xxm.sourceforge.net/tutorial01/index.html) on a clean Windows install, and made screenshots at every step. I haven't made much tutorials before, and wouldn't even know where to start to make one of those walk-through video's with a voice-over...

Is it clear enough? How could I improve it? (First thing that comes up to mind is I should have set the screen to 800x600)

Should I extend this tutorial with how to include fragments on pages or how to debug a project, or should I make new tutorials about those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a programmer or an I.T. person (who is already technically-inclined) that understands the shortcuts and shorthand notations (virt-dir, for example), it's quite good. Although, looking at the website, it should cover running as a standalone HTTP server, as this is claimed to be supported.

Comment: Good point, I'll include that.

Comment: For your information, I've redone the screenshots at 800x600 and included a few more to demo xxmHttp and xxmHttpSvc